# UICollectionView Swipe/Move only to left and disable temporarily swiping right

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swipe

I have a UICollectionView and on each cell, user need to answer before moving to next page. I want to enable swiping to right action only if user selects an answer on the current cell. However, user can move to left without any limitations. 
Can you give me any idea how to disable UICollectionView swipe to right direction temporarily and letting user it once user selects an answer?

Comment: Maybe, only add the next question cell after the user has answered the previous questions.

Comment: Yes, @Sam is right. It is possible to load next cell If user answered it.

Comment: The model from the API is very complicated. @Sam do you suggest me to reload the collecitonview every time user answer the question on the current cell with the next question added into the collectionview datasource?

Comment: You should look into the `performBatchUpdates` method on `UICollectionView`. It is similar in spirit to the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods of `UITableView`